# ehcache keySet timed out when using getKeysWithExpiryCheck() method

Tags: java, cluster-computing, ehcache, terracotta

I am using ehcache to control user sessions, every once in a while I see this error in the log upon users login.

```
net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.NonStopCacheException: keySet timed out
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.concurrency.NonStopCacheKeySet$NonStopCacheKeySetIterator$1.performClusterOperationTimedOut(NonStopCacheKeySet.java:103)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.concurrency.NonStopCacheKeySet$NonStopCacheKeySetIterator$1.performClusterOperationTimedOut(NonStopCacheKeySet.java:96)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.store.ExecutorServiceStore.executeClusterOperation(ExecutorServiceStore.java:1187)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.store.NonstopStoreImpl.executeClusterOperation(NonstopStoreImpl.java:704)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.concurrency.NonStopCacheKeySet$NonStopCacheKeySetIterator.<init>(NonStopCacheKeySet.java:96)
    at net.sf.ehcache.constructs.nonstop.concurrency.NonStopCacheKeySet.iterator(NonStopCacheKeySet.java:56)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getKeysWithExpiryCheck(v.java:1906)
...
```

The [official ehcache doucmentation](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Cache.html#getKeysWithExpiryCheck()) says: "Consider whether your usage requires checking for expired keys. Because this method takes so long, depending on cache settings,...".

So I am not really sure what timeout in the ecache.xml to increase to stop this error even though 20000 ms seems like more than enough to me, because the documentation also mentioned that the time taken is approximately 200ms per 1000 entries.

This is the used ehcache.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache name="RelianceCache" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">


    <cache name="READ_USERS_CACHE" maxElementsInMemory="0" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false">
        <terracotta clustered="true" valueMode="serialization"  consistency="strong">
            <nonstop immediateTimeout="false" timeoutMillis="20000">
                <timeoutBehavior type="exception" />
            </nonstop>
        </terracotta>
    </cache>


    <terracottaConfig url="TSA_SERVERS:TSA_PORT" rejoin="true" />
</ehcache>
```

Edit:
See [the NonStopCacheKeySet implementation](http://svn.terracotta.org/svn/ehcache/tags/ehcache-core-2.5.7/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/nonstop/concurrency/NonStopCacheKeySet.java), the error is being thrown in the method `NonStopCacheKeySetIterator`.

Comment: Can you give information about the size of the cache when this happens? Or the lifecycle of your app compared to the starting of the Terracotta server?

Comment: This cache contains the logged in users, so I can guarantee the size to be less than 100 entries. I am not really sure what you mean by lifecycle of my app compared to Terracotta server.

Comment: I added some debug messages in the ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar, because the original exception cause is lost.

Comment: Regarding lifecycle: Is there a chance that your application tries to access the clustered cache before the Terracotta server is started?

Comment: Well, not in this case, the Terracotta server is running for sure, the problem doesn't always occur, meaning that sometimes the user would get this error and most times not.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing timeout will not solve the problem. 20 seconds for 100 entries is extraordinary long.

If it's appropriate from application logic point of view I would consider changing timeoutBehavior to `timeoutBehavior="localReadsAndExceptionOnWrite"`. Please note, that `localCacheEnabled` property must be TRUE which is default value.

```
   ...
   <terracotta clustered="true" localCacheEnabled="true" valueMode="serialization"  consistency="strong">
        <nonstop immediateTimeout="false" timeoutMillis="20000">
            <timeoutBehavior type="localReadsAndExceptionOnWrite" />
        </nonstop>
    </terracotta>
    ...
```

---

Another solution could be changing consistency to the default value `consistency ="eventual"`. This will most probably solve the problem but could lead to the temporaly stale data returned by the cache.

---

As the documentation states "Consider whether your usage requires checking for expired keys...". Would it be possible to adjust the application logic to use Cache.getKey() instead of iteration through the list of keys?